# Download .ics from website to Android calendar

Tags: php, android, ios, calendar, icalendar

I have a problem with .ics files and the calendar on my smartphone. First, to create an ICS file and download it, I use this function :

```
function createEventCalendar($start, $end, $description, $location) {
    $event = array();
    $rand = rand(5, 1000000000);

    $event['name'] = "event";
    $event['data'] = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:-//blabla//blabla//FR\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nDTSTAMP:".date('Ymd\THis')."\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\nUID:".$rand."\nDTSTART:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($start))."\nDTEND:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($end))."\nSUMMARY:Rendez-vous assurance\nDESCRIPTION:".$description."\nLOCATION:".$location."\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR\r\n";

    return $event;
}

public function downloadEventCalendar($event) {
    $eventname = $event['name'].'.ics';

    header("Content-Type: text/x-vCalendar");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$eventname."\"");

    echo $event['data'];
    exit();
}
```

For my exemple the `DTEND` finish 1 hours after the `DTSTART`. My problem is when I download this file from my XPERIA and click on the event `event.ics`, i choose `Default account : Calendar of the device` and the event is never imported and the screen is blocked, as you can see :

[image: screen blocked on this picture]

Did I forget to add a parameter for android ? because it works for IOS.

**UPDATE** : here the ICS generated code

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//blaBla//blaBla//FR
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20150804T095037
STATUS:CONFIRMED
UID:495370174
DTSTART:20150901T120000
DTEND:20150901T130000
SUMMARY:My summary
DESCRIPTION:Description of the event
LOCATION:My calendar
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly, i found a solution !

When i created the content of my file, i used `\n`, we need to use `\r\n` at the end of each lines like this :

```
$event['data'] = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\nPRODID:-//blabla//blabla//EN\r\nBEGIN:VEVENT\r\nDTSTAMP:".date('Ymd\THis')."\r\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\r\nUID:".$rand."\r\nDTSTART:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($start))."\r\nDTEND:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($end))."\r\nSUMMARY:my summary\r\nDESCRIPTION:".$description."\r\nLOCATION:".$location."\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\nEND:VCALENDAR";
```

And to download the file i use header, the right one is :

```
header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$eventname."\"");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's several problems with your generated iCalendar file. I would suggest you try an online validator. If you still have issues after that, you should share the actual generated iCalendar, not the code that generates it (especially if it's all on one line :/)

Comment: I passed my `event.ics` to validator, and corrected some errors, but it doesn't work anyway. I updated my code with the generate `ICS` code. I added `\r\n` at the end of my code. Do you see any errors ?

Comment: I found a website who do what I want [here](https://addthisevent.com/), I tried to copy the `event.ics` generated in my code. After download, and get exactly the same code generated in `event.ics`, mine doesn't work...

Comment: Hi Remi, I saw some `strtotime` statements, and thought there were no `date()` functions around them, which is why I thought it was wrong. The new formatting helps.

One common issue is that some clients don't support floating times well. Try appending a `Z` to your DTSTART and DTEND to see if that solves it.